# I've a sql database file I want to use asp_regsql.exe tool to put asp.net membership provider

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, visual-studio

I've a sql database file  I want to use asp_regsql.exe tool to put asp.net membership provider
[image: The connection that I use]

The main problem that I can't use the asp_regsql.exe to add the tables that I need , 
I tried various  of connections  , 
If some one got a CREATE sql file that contains the membership table construction it would help ,

Thank you in advance

Comment: What you have shown isn't the asp_regsql.exe tool - what happens when you try to use the tool? It is supposed to do this for you

Comment: I meant to show what type of connection I use , so no misleading happens between it and sql express :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this tip](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/126363/How-to-create-Aspnetdb-database) I have written in code project.  Simply, you can call the following once:

```
System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install("YOUR_DATABASE", SqlFeatures.All, "YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the SQL script @ %WINDOWS%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallCommon.sql 
Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203214/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040506-1.aspx